# Selecting a deeply nested div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to move the inline style of the div id="awards" to css, but thus far have only been able to make it work inline. also I'd like to style the h3 within the div, but have been unable to correctly identify that selector either. Any ideas on how I would identify the div and h3 in css?

I've tried a bunch of different selectors in my stylesheet, but I thought this would work, but it does not.

```
#awards {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-size: 100%;
    bottom: 20%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}
```

Here is the code for the rendered page

```
<body class="home page page-id-7 page-template page-template-page-home page-template-page-home-php unknown">
<div id="slideNav">
    <a href="javascript:jQuery.pageslide.close()" class="closeBtn"></a>
    <div id="mobileNav">
    <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation" class="mainNav"><li id="menu-item-43" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-43"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-44" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-46" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-48" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-48"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/category/press/">Press</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-49"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/category/awards/">Awards</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-45" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container" style="opacity: 1;">    
<div id="header">   

    <div class="inside clearfix">

                <div id="logo">

            <h1 class="logo"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com"><img src="http://dev.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/logo-block-white-option-21.png" alt="Gallagher Construction" title=""></a></h1>

        </div>

        <div id="mainNav" class="clearfix">                         
            <div class="menu-main-navigation-container"><ul id="menu-main-navigation-1" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-7 current_page_item menu-item-43"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-44"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/services/">Services</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-46"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-48"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/category/press/">Press</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-49"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/category/awards/">Awards</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-45"><a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul></div>         
        </div>

        <a href="#slideNav" class="menuToggle"></a> 

        <div id="sidebar" class="clearfix"> 




    </div><!-- end sidebar -->  

    </div>  

</div>


<div id="middle" class="clearfix">  
<div id="content" class="full"> 

        <div class="slideshow">         
            <ul class="slides">


                <li id="slide1" class="post-9 slide type-slide status-publish hentry" style="height: 753px; background-image: url(http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/313-FRONT-SLIDE.jpg);">                              
                        <div class="details" style="margin-top: -143.5px; display: block;">
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="inside">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h2>Beautiful.&nbsp;Solid. Quality.</h2>
<h5>Full service construction focusing on quality craftsmanship from foundation to finish.</h5>
<p><a href="/portfolio/" target="_parent" style="background-color:#6D2727;" class="ttsc_button button ">View Our Homes</a></p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>                  
                        </div>                                  
                    <div class="awards">
                        <h3>2014 CATT Residential Project of the Year Winner</h3>
                        <h3>Tahoe Quarterly Mountain Home Awards Winner</h3>
                    </div>
                </li>           
                            </ul>               
    </div>

    <div id="slideshowNav" class="inactive">

                <a id="slideshowNavBtn1" class="active" href="#slide1"></a>     

    </div>

    </div>
</div>

    <div id="footer">



        <div class="secondary">
            <div class="inside clearfix">   
                                    <div class="left"><p>© 2015 <a href="http://www.gallagherconstructiontahoe.com"><strong>Gallagher Construction</strong></a> All Rights Reserved.</p></div>
            <div class="right"><p><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/about/">About</a> | <a href="/services/">Services | </a><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a> | <a href="/category/press/">Press</a> | <a href="/category/awards/">Awards</a> | <a href="/contact/">Contact</a></p></div><a href="/contact/">
            </a></div><!-- end footer inside--><a href="/contact/">     
        </a></div><!-- end footer secondary--><a href="/contact/">      

    </a></div><!-- end footer --><a href="/contact/">
</a></div><!-- end container --><a href="/contact/">

    <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#tabs').tab();

            $('#accordion2').collapse({
              toggle: true
            });
        }); 
    </script></body>
```

Comment: awards is a class. So: .awards{} and the h3 .awards h3 {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, to access a class from css you have to do like this: `.awards`
not `#awards`. You only use '#' for id's only.

Second - Either you can do:

```
div h3 {
...
}
```

Which will access all 'h3's in the div.

Or you can add a class or id to the h3

If you have anymore questions, or if something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks!  .awards {} and .awards > h3 {}

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access immediate child of div with awards class.

```
.awards>h3{
...
}
```

To identify all h3 tags under awards

```
.awards h3{
...
}
```